# Mongoose Duplicate Indexing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am using array to store ObjectId's but even the duplicate Id's are being 
saved

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const as = new Schema({
    aId: [{
                  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                  ref: 'js',
              }],
    jId: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'jb',
   },
});

as.index({ aId: 1 }, { unique: true });
module.exports = mongoose.model('applicants', as);
```

in database the aId ObjectId are stored as serially 0,1,2,3 on....
but even using index the id's are saved duplicately,

```
  {
   "_id" : ObjectId("5881b4bc745dbf49176e5cc6"),
   "jId" : ObjectId("5881ab61745dbf49176e5cc5"),
   "aId" : [
       ObjectId("58819a25e381142fb0aa2214"),
       ObjectId("5881b76e0e17c5500fe8284b")
       ObjectId("5881b76e0e17c5500fe8284b")
   ],
   "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: @ExplosionPills is correct in his answer. As a side note, I'd recommend that you come up with more expressive names for your variables.  If anyone has to maintain this code, they'll get frustrated quickly.  As Uncle Bob says, "Write your code as if it will be maintained by a psychopath who knows where you live"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-unique/):

> The unique constraint applies to separate documents in the collection. That is, the unique index prevents separate documents from having the same value for the indexed key, but the index does not prevent a document from having multiple elements or embedded documents in an indexed array from having the same value

You need to handle unicity of the array yourself. Fortunately, [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator cal help you keep the array values unique when you update applicants.